# how to change url action form if data not matches

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have a form in a controller :

```
$form=$this->createForm(new ServiceCityFormType());

$request = $this->getRequest();

      if( $request->isMethod('POST') && $form->isValid() ) {

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $form->getData();

      }

      return ; //the actual page
```

This form contain two fields:
- cityPostalCode
- cityName

The form is made to know if my business have some interventions in the city postal code filled by user (to delivery for example). 
So I compare if the postalCode intervention of my business matched with the postalCode submit in the form.

This is the request in another controller:

```
// recover the request method here POST
$request = $this->getRequest();

// store the field data input
$postData = $request->request->get('service_city_form'); // note that the form is a service in my app
$postalCode = $postData['cityPostalCode'];
$cityName = $postData['cityName'];

$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$postalCodeIntervention = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('EntityBundle:Intervention')
->findOneByPostalCodeIntervention($postalCode);

if (!$postalCodeIntervention) {
// here i redirect to an error page
} else {
// redirect to the good page       
}
```

Here the view containing my form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    {{ form_label(form.cityPostalCode, "(*)  Entrez un code postal :", {'label_attr': {'class': 'mdl-textfield__label'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.cityPostalCode) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.cityPostalCode, {'attr': {'class': 'cityPostalCode mdl-textfield__input', 'type' : 'text', 'autocomplete': 'off'}}) }}
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top: 0.3cm;">
    {{ form_label(form.cityName) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.cityName) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.cityName) }}
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top: 0.3cm;">
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
  </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

My question is simple: I would like to set the action url dynamically and directly when the form is submitted and in the same controller.
That is to say not compare in another controller the POST data submit, but directly in the same page.

So when I submit the form, the action url change if data not matched (return the error page), and change if data matched (return the good page).

Comment: `header("Location: yourpage");` ? Also there are ways to redirect using symfony.. did you even search google for this?!

Comment: @Naruto, I have searched on the web for some solutions, but none match with my specific case for now, I am still searching.

Comment: What you want to do is return a [redirect response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting) if your condition is met. Also you might want to have a look at [current symfony best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html).

Comment: @Yoshi funny thing is, your first link is the second link in google.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do some really nasty stuff in Javascript.

But honestly I would just send the `$_POST` data to a validator script which then sends the info/user to the right page. It is really the most semantic way.

Comment: you suggest me to recover `$_POST` data after submission (did it means that the action is not set first in the form ?), and build the comparison method/request and choose to redirect to the right route according to the matched result ?

Comment: exactly. You build the comparison on the action location and then take the appropriate actions from there. either redirect them to the location they need to be or query certain info to a database etc.